# How to set end date relative to start date in date range field

Tags: datetime

Is it possible to set the end date relative to the selected start date in a D8 date range field?
I have a date range field that I use to specify an accounting period. The end date should now be put to one year minus one day from the selected start date. For example, the start date 2016-07-01 will give the end date 2017-06-30.
How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The current widgets in core for the Datetime Range module do not allow this.

You would need to create a custom widget for this.  Off the top of my head, I would create one that extends `DateRangeWidgetBase()` and mostly mirrors what `DateRangeDefaultWidget()` does, except to collect a relative period in a plain text field for the end date.  Then, add a `massageFormValues()` function to turn the relative date into an absolute one, and then call `parent::massageFormValues()`.  You may also be able to do this with a `#process` callback on the end date element, but I forget which of the two runs first during form processing.

Comment: And as a side note, if you get this working, it would be a great addition to the https://www.drupal.org/project/datetime_extras module if you post it as a patch.

Comment: And just altering the node form and adding a custom submit to populate the end field? Couldn't that work as well?

Comment: @leymannx The timestamp/datetime/daterange default widgets use HTML5 elements, which complicate matters.  You also need to convert to a proper date before the massageFormValues (which tweaks the values for date-only and sets the storage time zone) and validation (which is at both the element and widget level) runs.  This is messy in a node form alter.  Doing this as a new field Widget is the easiest option.